# How to fill associative array with sql query?

Tags: php, sql

I want to pick color for day according to the availability with just one query. For example if monday 10:00 is booked, it should be red. I used associative array for getting data from mysql and use it for processing. It gives me error like second parameter of array_in should be array. Furthermore, associative array does not work properly either. Let say if I have two bookings on monday, it took only one of them.

```
<?php
    $nome=7;

    $mydb = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
    $myquery = "SELECT day, time FROM reserve";
    $result = mysqli_query($mydb, $myquery);


    $data_array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data_array[$row['day']] = $row['time'];
    }
    print_r($data_array);


$times = ['08:00', '09:00','10:00', '11:00', '12:00',  '13:00'];

?>





   <TABLE class="myTimetable"> 
  <THEAD>
   <TR>
  <TH></TH>
  <TH>Monday</TH>
  <TH>Tuesday</TH>
  <TH>Wednesday</TH>
  <TH>Thursday</TH>
  <TH>Friday</TH>     
  </TR>
 </THEAD>
 <TBODY>

 <?php

foreach($times as $time)
 {?>
<tr>
<?php
    $nome=$nome+1;
    echo "<td><div id=$nome>$time</div></td>";
    foreach($data_array as $aa => $bb)
    {

        if(in_array($time , $bb))
        {
            echo "<td class='available'></td>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<td class='notAvailable'></td>";
        }
    }
   ?>
  </tr>
 <?php
 }

?>


    </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
```

Comment: I think this line `if(in_array($time , $bb))` should be `if(in_array($bb , $times))` as you said and php documentation specifies the second param of in_array must be an array

Comment: Your data array should be set up like this so you can have more than 1 time per day $data_array[$row['day']][] = $row['time'];

Comment: This would be much easier with PDO.